# How Azure Search service works with Azure Bot & Language Cognitive Service

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-bot-service

I am looking for documentation, blogs or article where I can learn how Azure bot works with Azure Search Service and Language Cognitive Service.
Any reference to document/architecture flow will be highly appreciated.

I have searched MS documentation, but so I couldn't find article beyond their individual usage and benefits.
I am looking for some detailed information about how information (Chat communication) flows among Bot app service, Search Service, Language Cognitive service and ultimately to knowledgebase (Language Custom Question answering)
[image]

I am curious to learn how search service is used for document indexing and searching QnA pairs,
How it interact with Bot service, Language service  and KB

Thank you.

Comment: Here it explains how to integrate both at a high level https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/ai/conversational-bot
Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Hello @Jdresc , Thank you for this link, i have seen this link already, and the flow in the diagram given is exactly how i assume it to be.
Moreover i am curious to know how document indexing work on KB with help of Search service, and how language cognitive service play role when BOT to KB communication happens.
It would be great if something get to read about Bot Cognition and Intelligence section from the diagram

Answer (score 1):

**LUIS (Language Understanding)** is the best approach to work with azure search service and azure bot language cognitive service. There is professional documentation to learn the architecture. LUIS is having a hybrid method to implement the cognitive services in language service and bot in combine for ***IoT applications, Chat bot, and E-Commerce chat bots.***

https://www.luis.ai/

Check the above link to learn the architecture.

**Note:** Based on architecture, we need to learn from this link and internally we have few more links in resources section. Check the screen below to navigate to the resources section to get official documentation.

[image]

**Extended Answer:**

To answer the questions asked in comment, whether "**Bot service makes use of Language service and app service makes use of Search service**". Then there is question asked to the bot it has to access the application service which was hosted using the azure cognitive services. Then the service was connected successfully, the language is the major part which the bot need to identify. The way of architecture shown in the question is the way they will work and also the below architecture is an another example of implementation

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello @SairamTadepalli-MT , i think the whole Azure Bot LUIS, QnAMaker, Text Analytics  has been migrated newly introduced Custom Question Answering, and here the LUIS part is upgraded with Azure Cognitive Service for Language, 
My question remains same that how Language Cognitive Service and Search Service Works hand in hand, is it the way shown in above diagram that Bot service makes use of Language service and app service makes use of Search service, 
Basically when user ask question in webchat how information flow ?

Comment: Kindly check the extended answer.